# Calculating the execution time of nested for loops

Tags: c

Suppose i have a nested for-loop and if-checks shown below, if i wanted to see how many clock cycles (ultimately how many secs) a particular for-loop or if-check is taking to finish executing.

Should the sum of number of clock cycles (secs) taken by the inner for-loop and if-check be equal (or approximately equal) to the number of clock cycles(secs) taken by the outer most for-loop.?

Or am i doing it wrong? how do i time the loops if there's any other way of doing it.?

Note: I have 3 different functions doing pretty much the same thing, i have declared 3 different functions to measure each for-loop or if-check separately 'cause if i try to get the execution time of all the sub components in the same piece of code, then the number of clock cycles(secs) taken by the outer for-loop will include some extra execution of instructions which are calculating the clock cycles count of inner for-loop and if-check i guess.

```
void fun1(){
       int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    clock_t t=0,t_start=0,t_end=0;
    //time the outermost forloop
    t_start = clock();
    for(i=0;i<100000;i++){
            for(j=0;j<1000;j++){
                    //some code
                    }
            if(k==0){
              //some code
                 }
            }
    t_end = clock();
    t=t_end-t_start;
    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("outer for-loop took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);
 }

void fun2(){
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    clock_t t2=0,t2_start=0,t2_end=0;
    for(i=0;i<100000;i++){
            //time the inner for loop
            t2_start=clock();
            for(j=0;j<1000;j++){
                    //some code
                    }
            t2_end=clock();
            t2+=(t2_end-t2_start);

            if(k==0){
                 //some code
                     }
            }
    double time_taken = ((double)t2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("inner for-loop took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);
  }

 void fun3(){
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    clock_t t3=0,t3_start=0,t3_end=0;
    for(i=0;i<100000;i++){
            for(j=0;j<1000;j++){
                 //some code
                       }
            //time the if check
            t3_start=clock();
            if(k==0){
                    //some code
                    }
            t3_end=clock();
            t3+=(t3_end-t3_start);
            }
    double time_taken = ((double)t3)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("if-check took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);
  }
```

Comment: Are you doing it wrong?  It depends on what your objective is.  In many cases, Big O (the time complexity of your code) is more important than raw speed.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding;  Consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces, (not tabs)

Answer (score 0):

The expected answer is `t` in `fun1` will likely be *slightly* more than `t2+t3` from `fun2` and `fun3` respectively, representing the additional time to evaluate the outer loop itself.

Less obvious, however, is the time added by the measurement itself, which will be the time to invoke `clock()` itself once for each measurement.  When measuring the inside loops, it's effectively multiplied by 100,000 because of the iteration of the outer loop.

Here's a program to measure the measurement itself, and for good measure, also measures the time to evaluate an empty outer loop.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    clock_t t = 0;
    clock_t t_start, t_end;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        t_start = clock();
        t_end = clock();
        t += (t_end - t_start);
    }
    double time_taken = ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf ("Time imposed by measurement itself: %fsec\n", time_taken);


    t_start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    }
    t_end = clock();
    t = (t_end - t_start);
    time_taken = ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf ("Time to evaluate the loop: %fsec\n", time_taken);
}
```

Which, at least on my system, suggests the measurement may skew the results some:

```
Time imposed by measurement itself: 0.056949sec
Time to evaluate the loop: 0.000200sec
```

To get the amount of time your inner loops "really" take, you'll need to subtract out that added by the act of measuring it.